# Can't hide Bottom Sheet, Android

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

I'm having problems with my [bottom-sheet](/questions/tagged/bottom-sheet) because when I open the activity it is on, blocking the view
[image]

This happens, I think, because of the XML attribute declaring the [bottom-sheet](/questions/tagged/bottom-sheet) with 350dp of height:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

The thing is, I can't change that value to 0dp because the next time when I try to open the [bottom-sheet](/questions/tagged/bottom-sheet), there is no [bottom-sheet](/questions/tagged/bottom-sheet), because the height is 0dp, so it won't show anything. 
My question is, is there a way to declare the [bottom-sheet](/questions/tagged/bottom-sheet) off? (I've tried to setState to STATE_COLLAPSED but didn't work).
Bellow is the java code that interacts with the Bottom Sheet.
 JAVA:

```
View bottomSheet = findViewById( R.id.bottom_sheet );
        mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    //mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
                    //mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    //mBottomSheetBehavior.isHideable();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write this:

```
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
```

Comment: hello there acctualy i have a diffrent isuue where if i go to a fragment from a button click which is in the bottom sheet the fragment is opening but the bottom sheet is not hiding automaticly in the other fragment i have to do it manaully by tap on the screen here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69282868/bottomsheet-is-not-hiding-when-navigating-between-different-fragments can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 21):

first you have to add the attribute

```
app:behavior_hideable="true"
```

in your

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
```

And then you can hide the bottom sheet using

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)
```

and not

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
```

the state COLLAPSED is between HIDDEN and EXPANDED and his heigth must be specified by the attribute:

```
app:behavior_peekHeight="200dp"
```

Comment: bottom sheet does not show when i setstate COLLAPSED. I have app:behavior_peekHeight="200dp" in xml code

Comment: just wondering, are your bottomsheet a first child in a CoordinatorLayout?

Comment: hello there acctualy i have a diffrent isuue where if i go to a fragment from a button click which is in the bottom sheet the fragment is opening but the bottom sheet is not hiding automaticly in the other fragment i have to do it manaully by tap on the screen here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69282868/bottomsheet-is-not-hiding-when-navigating-between-different-fragments can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was using `BottomSheetDialog`.

**`app:behavior_hideable`** - attribute is used to determine **if our bottom sheet will hide when it is swiped down**. In other words bottom sheet top be off screen, if the peek height isn’t set.

**`app:behavior_peekHeight`** - attribute value used to represent how much pixels the bottom sheet will be visible.

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:elevation="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDerived"
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"> ........... </LinearLayout>
```

I set the peekHeight to 50dp. And peek height has nothing to do with the bottomSheet layout height itself which I set 200dp (for example only).

[image: peek]

You can view the changes in your XML viewer if the bottom sheet is expanded, if so add the `app:behavior_peekHeight = 0dp`from the xml layout and it will hide and also inform you of the current state.

Comment: hello there acctualy i have a diffrent isuue where if i go to a fragment from a button click which is in the bottom sheet the fragment is opening but the bottom sheet is not hiding automaticly in the other fragment i have to do it manaully by tap on the screen here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69282868/bottomsheet-is-not-hiding-when-navigating-between-different-fragments can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 3):

In my case i was not able to hide the bottomsheet and it was placed on top of my view. I found out that `animateLayoutChanges = "true"` in my layout file was causing this issue.

Comment: I have removed animateLayoutChanges = "true" and it is working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: hello there acctualy i have a diffrent isuue where if i go to a fragment from a button click which is in the bottom sheet the fragment is opening but the bottom sheet is not hiding automaticly in the other fragment i have to do it manaully by tap on the screen here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69282868/bottomsheet-is-not-hiding-when-navigating-between-different-fragments can anyone help me with this

Comment: You saved my time. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inside `onCreate` add these lines, it can hide the bottombar

```
mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true); //Important to add
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN); //Important to add
```

Answer (score 0):

When Collapsed set app:behavior_hideable="false"

Answer (score 0):

You need to just simply add the below code and it works perfectly.

To hide the bottomsheet:-

```
bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
```

To show the bottomsheet:-

```
 bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
```

Answer (score -1):

You can manually hide that bottom sheet by setting the visibility of the parent linear layout to gone
put this line in your code when you want to hide it.

firstly check if its showing otherwise hide it.

`if (confirmLayoutBehaviour.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) { //todo hide your bottom sheet if its already open confirmLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); } else { //set it to visible if its not open confirmLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }`

it worked for me please try it