# BottomSheet is not hiding when navigating between different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog

Hello there I have a `bottomsheet` with some textViews (as button) when pressed it navigates to a diffrent fragment but the issue is when `textView` is pressed and navigated to the fragment still the bottom sheet is not hiding evantually have to tap on the screen for hiding the bottom sheet , I want that when the fragment is launched the bottom sheet will hide, here is a screen recording of what issue im getting [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KF-aSjSQ3MeQMH-RV6Zkk9ICuDJVluDK/view?usp=sharing)

**Profile_Fragment.java**

```
 ImageView accountSettings = view.findViewById(R.id.account_Settings);
  accountSettings.setOnClickListener(
                v -> {
                    BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet();
                    bottomSheet.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheet.getTag());
                }
        );
```

**BottomSheet.java**

```
public class BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    public BottomSheet() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_profile, container, false);
       

        TextView settingsProfileTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.settings);
        settingsProfileTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Fragment settings_profile = new Settings_Profile();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, settings_profile);
            transaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(settings_profile));
            transaction.commit();
          
        });
        TextView editProfileTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
        editProfileTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Fragment edit_profile = new Edit_Profile();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, edit_profile);
            transaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(edit_profile));
            transaction.commit();
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Edit_Profile.java** // the fragment which is being open when textView is pressed

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);
        profilePhoto = view.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
        initImageLoader();
        setProfileImage();
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.backArrow);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Fragment newCase = new Profile_Fragment();
            assert getFragmentManager() != null;
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newCase);
            transaction.disallowAddToBackStack();
            transaction.commit();
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Add these lines before transaction.commit() in settingsProfileTextView Click listener.      mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);

Comment: sorry i have  added it but it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BottomSheet` is hosted by a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.
Internally it has a `Dialog` that can be dismissed using `dismiss()` which will eventually dismiss the `BottomSheet`.

Applying that in your code whenever a fragment transaction is committed:

```
    settingsProfileTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Fragment settings_profile = new Settings_Profile();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, settings_profile);
        transaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(settings_profile));
        transaction.commit();
        dismiss(); // Dismiss the Bottom sheet
      
    });
    TextView editProfileTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
    editProfileTextView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Fragment edit_profile = new Edit_Profile();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, edit_profile);
        transaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(edit_profile));
        transaction.commit();
        dismiss(); // Dismiss the Bottom sheet
    });
```